# how to multiply two array value without loop in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, array-map

I have tried to multiply `$qty_test` **and** `$get_ltr` also that data type is an integer, but that give me error

> Unsupported operand types

what is issued in the code.

```
$qty_test=explode(",",$request->input('qty'));

foreach ($part_id as $part_ids) {
     $get_ltr = part::where('status',1)->where('part_no',$part_ids)->first();
     $ltr[] = $get_ltr->ltr;
     $total_ltr= $qty_test * $ltr; 
}
```

that gives me error how to multiply it please help me.

Comment: Because $ltr is array. You can't use multiplication for arrays in php. And $qty_test looks like array too. (explode returns array of string as a result)

Comment: Why do you use `$ltr[] ` instead of `$ltr`?

Comment: @dhara gosai: $qty_test and  $get_ltr->ltr both are array?

Comment: @SaurabhDhariwal both are array

Comment: @dharagosai i updated my answer only get multiplication of each row qty and ltr in array

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
$total_ltr = array_map(function () {
    return array_sum(func_get_args());
}, $qty_test, $get_ltr->ltr);
```

Answer (score 0):

To get all row multiplication

```
$qty_test=explode(",",$request->input('qty'));

foreach ($part_id as $part_ids) {
     $get_ltr = part::where('status',1)->where('part_no',$part_ids)->first();
     $ltr = $get_ltr->ltr;
     $total_ltr[]= $qty_test * $ltr; 
}
print_r($total_ltr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are forgotten $qty_test have array value after you use explode(). So you have to use array_sum() to sum all of your $qty_test array and multiply this with your respective value.

Try this

```
$qty_test=explode(",",$request->input('qty'));

foreach ($part_id as $part_ids) {
   $get_ltr = part::where('status',1)->where('part_no',$part_ids)->first();
   $ltr[] = $get_ltr->ltr;
}

$total_ltr= array_sum($qty_test) * array_sum($ltr); 
echo $total_ltr;
```

**Hope this will help you**

Comment: i required each row of multiplication not first all qty sum and then multiply with ltr.

Comment: that answer not give me each row of mulitiplication i dont required to sum ,only i got the multiplication of each row qty and ltr

Answer (score 0):

you need to used `array_sum` method here

> first of the sum of both array one by one look like this..

for example

```
$arrayOne = [5,10,15];    //total is 30
$arrayTwo = [5,10];       //total is 15  
$sumOfTwoArray = array_sum($arrayOne) * array_sum($arrayTwo);
```

> output is(30 *15)  : 450

now in your code modify like that

```
$qty_test=explode(",",$request->input('qty'));

foreach ($part_id as $part_ids) {
     $get_ltr = part::where('status',1)->where('part_no',$part_ids)->first();
     $ltr[] = $get_ltr->ltr;
 }
$total_ltr= array_sum($qty_test) * array_sum($ltr);  //used array_sum method here in both array
```

only get multiplication of each row qty and ltr then used like that

```
 $array = [5,10,15];
 $ltr = ['5','10'];

 $array1 =  array_map(function ($v) use ($array) {
           info("v ;- ".$v);
         return array_map(function ($a) use ($v){
                info("a :- ".$a." v :- ".$v);
                return   $a * $v;
          },$array);
  },$ltr);

  //info("total is :- ".print_r($array1,true));
```

Answer (score 0):

**#1** - If you want to get each multiplication for each value, follow this code:

```
$qty_test=explode(",",$request->input('qty'));

$ltr = [];
foreach ($part_id as $part_ids) {

   $get_ltr = part::where('status',1)->where('part_no',$part_ids)->first();

   array_push($ltr, $get_ltr->ltr);

}

$total_ltr = [];
foreach($qty_test as $i=>$val){
    array_push($total_ltr, $qty_test[$i] * $ltr[$i]);
}
```

....

....

**#2** - But if you want to sum all values in `first array` and multiply it to the sum of values in `second array`, follow this code:

```
$qty_test=explode(",",$request->input('qty'));

$ltr = [];
foreach ($part_id as $part_ids) {

   $get_ltr = part::where('status',1)->where('part_no',$part_ids)->first();

   array_push($ltr, $get_ltr->ltr);

}

$total_ltr= array_sum($qty_test) * array_sum($ltr);
```

.

`array_sum()` will sum all values in an array, for example

```
echo array_sum([23,14,45]);

// will return 82 (23 + 14 + 45)
```

.

For more detail, you can refer to [Official PHP Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php) about `array_sum()`

Comment: that is also given same thing that count all qty + ltr first sum and then its give me multiplication .i required each qty * ltr multiply i dont required sum of all .

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late reply a while ago i have the situation to multiple all the values in array and finally created the function

for eg ;

```
$multiplicationArrays = ['10','10','50'];
```

is my array

and my expected result is `5000`

so i have created the function

```
function multiplyArray($numbersArray='')
    {
        //defining the error messages
        $errorMessage = "Minimum Two Numbers is required";
        //check if atleast two numbers in array
        $isMultiplicable = count($numbersArray);
        if ($isMultiplicable < 2 ) 
        {
            //if fails return the errormessage
           return $errorMessage;
        }
        else
        {
            //initializing the resilt as one for the first time
            $result = 1;
           foreach ($numbersArray as $numbersArray)
            {
                //on the each multiple an store it in the result varialbe
                $result *= $numbersArray;
            }
            //return the result
            return $result;
        }
    }
```

and finnaly pass the array inside the function

```
echo multiplyArray($multiplicationArrays);
```

and the result will be as expected `5000`

hope it helps